# Select2 and angular resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to implement select2 tags with angularJS and the problem is when I try to use angular resource:

```
Object.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(response) {
    $scope.ips = ['192.168.1.1', '127.0.1.1'];
});
$scope.options = {
    'simple_tags': true,
    'tags': [],
    'multiple': true
}
```

this is how my controller looks like. And in the html I have:

```
<input id="tags" class="input-block-level" multiple type="text" ui-select2="options" ng-model="ips" placeholder="Select ips">
```

It is not rendering the ips. Select2 works but I can't set the default values. If I put the $scope.ips array outside the Object.get, it works, so the problem is when I try to do it from ajax. Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `Object` here is, but if the problem is that the values are not updating, then the issue almost surely is that the code updating the value is not running in an `$digest` loop.

Manually starting the `$digest` loop should solve the problem. Hence, the following should work:

```js
Object.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(response) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.ips = ['192.168.1.1', '127.0.1.1'];
    });
});
```